# PDO returns no results while MySQL command line returns expected result

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, pdo, command-line-interface

I was working with database, running dynamically generated query. Everything was just fine, when I noticed problems with encoding in couple of rows in one table, so I repopulated it from backup and rebuilt the table.

After this action, PDO returns empty result and doesn't throw any exceptions, however, the same query with the same parameters executes successfully (returns some rows) from the command line. I copy-pasted both query and parameters from `var_dump()` output to run from command line.

The query:

```
SELECT `contracts_info`.`contract_number` AS `Номер контракта`, `contracts_info`.`balance` AS `Остаток`, `contracts_info`.`conclusion_date` AS `Дата заключения`, `contracts_info`.`activation_date` AS `Активация аккаунта`, `contracts_info`.`deactivation_date` AS `Деактивация аккаунта`,
`parents`.`mother_fullname` AS `ФИО матери`, `parents`.`mother_email` AS `E-mail матери`, `parents`.`mother_phone` AS `Телефон матери`, `parents`.`father_fullname` AS `ФИО отца`, `parents`.`father_email` AS `E-mail отца`, `parents`.`father_phone` AS `Телефон отца`, `parents`.`postal_office` AS `Отделение Новой почты`,
`students`.`name` AS `Имя`, `students`.`second_name` AS `Отчество`, `students`.`surname` AS `Фамилия`, `students`.`form_number` AS `Класс`, `students`.`form_letter` AS `Буква класса`, `students_info`.`medical_features` AS `Медицинские особенности`, `students_info`.`psychological_features` AS `Психологические особенности`
FROM contracts_info
JOIN `parents` USING(`contract_number`)
JOIN `students` USING(`contract_number`)
JOIN `students_info` USING(`contract_number`)
WHERE MATCH (`contracts_info`.`contract_number`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (`parents`.`contract_number`, `parents`.`mother_fullname`, `parents`.`mother_email`, `parents`.`father_fullname`, `parents`.`father_email`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (`students`.`name`, `students`.`second_name`, `students`.`surname`, `students`.`contract_number`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (`students_info`.`medical_features`, `students_info`.`psychological_features`, `students_info`.`contract_number`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Things I've tried or checked:

- checked credentials, used by script;
- run same query with different parameters - same result;
- run other queries by both methods - same result;
- tried running without backquotes - same result;
- rebuilt tables from php script - didn't help;
- skimmed table dumps in html - they are up-to-date;
- compared html table dumps and cli dumps - they are similar;
- checked if php queries have effect on results, acquired by cli commands - yes, there is an effect (so, both use the same server/database)

I've run out of ideas where I made a mistake and what to fix, so I want borrow yours =)
Even the craziest.

What is the problem?

Where am I mistaking?

Could be this server fault? I share nginx server and hosting with other sites and programmers and some of them may have access to my database.

MySQL version(): 5.6.29-76.2, PHP 5.5.9

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: PDO handling

PDO handling is encapsulated in the class

Creating PDO:

```
    try
    {
        $this->handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . $this->database . ";host=" . $this->server,
            $this->user, $this->password);

        // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
        $this->handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $this->handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }
```

`Query()` method is used to run queries. It has such parameters: `$sql` - query string with '?', `$parameters` - parameters array.

```
    $statement = $this->handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        trigger_error($this->handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

    if ($results !== false)
    {
        return $statement->fetchAll($this->PDOFetchMode);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Method for changing `$this->PDOFetchMode`

```
public function SetPDOFetchMode($pdo_constant)
{
    if (is_int($pdo_constant) && $pdo_constant >= 0)
        $this->PDOFetchMode = $pdo_constant;
}
```

Other code is about parameters validation, singleton implementation etc.

EDIT:

Inspired by this post: [PDO prepare statement and match against in boolean mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796205/pdo-prepare-statement-and-match-against-in-boolean-mode)

I tried binding parameters, but this didn't help

I've tried [Paul T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7644018/paul-t)'s advice about using parameters in a query directly according to his comment, but this didn't help either. Nevertheless, the query I got still successfully runs in CLI.

Comment: Can you add the PDO handling too, since PDO is in the title, question, and tag?

Comment: What MySQL version do you have? There was trouble in the past [with parameters in the AGAINST clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13682516/7644018).

Comment: Can you provide a sample `var_dump()` of the `$parameters` array?

Comment: @PaulT., `$parameters` array is usually a repetition of one single argument got from user as a query and it looks like '+word +word +*last_word*' but in local (Russian) language.

Comment: I was curious as to what the array might look like (language doesn't matter)  when there may be only 1 parameter, for example, or all 4 parameters and how it might affect the handling?  Does it fail when there are 4 parameters present?  Other than that, I'm running out of ideas. I noted earlier where you mentioned `encoding` ... was this with the character set or some other matter?

Comment: @PaulT., the problem with encoding is unclear too. I was loading a utf8 csv file into utf8 table, but there appeared some strange encoding failure with russian words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved pretty unusually by this post best answer:
[PDO + MySQL and broken UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475548/pdo-mysql-and-broken-utf-8-encoding)

After forcing to use utf8 encoding to the whole base using in constructor, it worked fine and results did appear. But I don't quite understand, how this was done. CLI requests returned results in utf8 encoding properly by default.

It seems that my `AGAINST` parameter was messed up with encoding.

**Code to fix it:**

```
$pdo = new PDO(
'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName',
'username',
'password',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

**Thanks [Paul T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7644018/paul-t) for inspiration**

Comment: That was a good find. Thanks for posting the discovered result!