# Using multiple phrases in MATCH/AGAINST search shows empty result

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I can't search 2 or more words but, when I search for a single word, everything is fine:

Follow my search query:

```php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search = $_POST['search-title'];
    $all_posts_query = "SELECT *, MATCH(title, tags, post_data) AGAINST('$search') AS score
    FROM posts 
    WHERE MATCH(title, tags, post_data) AGAINST('$search')
    ORDER BY score DESC";
    $all_posts_run = mysqli_query($con, $all_posts_query);
    $all_posts = mysqli_num_rows($all_posts_run);
    $total_pages = ceil($all_posts / $number_of_posts);
    $posts_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $number_of_posts;
}
```

When I type 'Best' (one word) it shows articles related to best but when i type 'Best food' (2 or more or even title of article) I get 0 results. And I'm new to php and mysql, so can someone change this into parameterized prepared statement to avoid sql injections if its not a lot of trouble?

Comment: Is the issue related to PHP? You are open to SQL injections. If `MATCH(title, tags, post_data) AGAINST('one two')` fails the issue is with the SQL, not PHP. Please narrow down the issue.

Comment: This command may not work the way you think it works. Take a look at this post's answers to get a better idea of things. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410632/mysql-match-against-example

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql match against ~ example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410632/mysql-match-against-example)