# mysql-match-is-not-giving-proper-result-when-searching-a-word-with-single-quote

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am looking for `"We've"` as complete word.
but below queries are returning a result for those column value that contains `"We"`

I want to use Match and AGAINST. Any suggestion please?

```
select *
from table as t 
where MATCH (t.column)
AGAINST ('We''ve*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);


select *
from table as t 
where MATCH (t.column)
AGAINST ('We\'ve*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Does [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9410866/2478398) solve your problem?

Comment: I doubt that `We've` is considered as single token during FT indexing. I think it is considered as two separate tokens - which are ignored due to minimal token length and stop-words list settings.

Comment: @Akina By default mysql does **not** consider `'` as a word separator, it is one of the few exceptions (`_` is the other I know of). Obviously, you can change this behaviour.